# Cocos2dx. Conditional action

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to create player moving using actions. I created function `void move(float x, float y)`; That function creates actions `RotateTo` and `MoveTo`. I want to move player only if angle between its `forward` and `target - forward` is less that some value; I tried to add `runAction(moveAction)` in `if` condition in `update` function with bool lock variable but any call of runAction inside `update` fails with `SIGSEGV` signal;

Here are fields of my class derived from Node:

```
cocos2d::Action* moveAction;
cocos2d::Action* rotationAction;
```

In move function:

```
void GameObject::move(float x, float y) {
  startPosition = getPosition();
  endPosition   = Vec2(x, y);

  stopAllActions();

  rotationAction = RotateTo::create(
      angleBetweenForwardAndTarget(endPosition) / rotateSpeed,
      -Mathf::normalizeAngle(Mathf::getAngle(lookAtPosition(endPosition)))
  );
  runAction(rotationAction);

  moveAction = MoveTo::create(
      endPosition.distance(startPosition) / moveSpeed,
      Vec2(x, y)
  );
  runAction(moveAction);
}
```

But now rotation and translation occurs in the same time
How to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transferred this question here http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/run-action-on-condition/42201